# Java - Make sure an object implements an interface

Tags: java, interface

EDIT: Solved, see below

Hi,

In Java, I got an object that could be of any class. BUT - that object will always have to implement an interface, so when I call methods defined by the interface, that object will contain that method.

Now, when you try to call a custom method on a generic object in Java, it mucks about typing. How can I somehow tell the compiler that my object does implement that interface, so calling the method is OK.

Basically, what I'm looking for is something like this:

```
Object(MyInterface) obj; // Now the compiler knows that obj implements the interface "MyInterface"
obj.resolve(); // resolve() is defined in the interface "MyInterface"
```

How can I do that in Java?

ANSWER: OK, if the interface is named MyInterface you can just put

```
MyInterface obj;
obj.resolve();
```

Sorry for not thinking before posting ....

Comment: *smile* - +1 for your last remark :-)

Answer (score 3):

You just do it with a [type cast](http://www.janeg.ca/scjp/oper/cast.html):

```
((MyInterface) object).resolve();
```

Usually it is best to do a check to make sure that this cast is valid -- otherwise, you'll get a [ClassCastException](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html).  You can't shoehorn anything that doesn't implement `MyInterface` into a `MyInterface` object. The way you do this check is with the `instanceof` operator:

```
if (object instanceof MyInterface) {
    // cast it!
}
else {
    // don't cast it!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (object instanceof MyInterface) {
    ((MyInterface) object).resolve();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
MyInterface a = (MyInterface) obj;
a.resolve();
```

or

```
((MyInterface)obj).resolve();
```

the java compiler uses the static type to check for methods, so you have to either cast the object to a type which implements your interface or cast to the interface itself.